# How to display and print data with PHP in a letter format (paper size)?

Tags: php, printing, wkhtmltopdf

I have an issue trying to print a report (in the server side), I'm using wkthtmltopdf libraries to print a specific report using the internal URL, the problem is that when I try to print this report in a letter format (and portrait)most of the times the report has more lines, so at the end my PDF report is out of format.

I tried to count the height lines in a regular letter page and then display my data in too columns if it's necessary, but this is not working for all the situations (there are over 300 reports).

How do you guys print reports using PHP?
or How do you guys set a letter page in PHP?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: or have you ever used a page break or something?

Answer (score 1):

I will typically just render the page in HTML then make a special CSS import with media="print" attribute. Then you can use plain CSS to format the page.

Comment: +1, this is what I do too. Here's [the media type spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) and [a good starting tutorial](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/).

Comment: well, I have some like that a PHP that feeds a plain html and then a CSS, but I always have the problem in the page break, for some reason.